Another asymmetry between $\land$ and $\lor$
Throughout $\def\f{\phi} \def\y{\psi}$ let $S$ be a set of sentences and $\f,\y$ be arbitirary sentences.

Recently I asked about the following 'asymmetry':
\begin{split}
\text{The following is true: } \ \ \ \ && S \vdash \f\land \y \iff S\vdash \f \text{ and } S\vdash \y\\
\text{The following is false: } \ \ \ \ && S \vdash \f\lor \y \iff S\vdash \f \text{ or } S\vdash \y
\end{split}
to which I was explained that the correct 'symmetry' lies in
\begin{split}
S \vdash \f\land \y & \iff S\vdash \f \text{ and } S\vdash \y\\
\f\lor\y \vdash S & \iff \f\vdash S \text{ and } \y\vdash S
\end{split}
Now, if $S$ is made complete and consistent, then it does follow that
$$S \vdash \f\lor \y \iff S\vdash \f \text{ or } S\vdash \y.$$
So my question is this: is there an analogous statement with $\land$ as opposed to $\lor$ that does not hold true unless $S$ is consistent and complete?
